# How to add and use npm package cryptocoins-icons in my AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, blur-admin

I am building a custom website built on top of template - [https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin](http://blur-admin)

I am new to npm. I wanted to use a npm package named cryptocoins-icons.
I went to my project folder root and ran the command `npm i cryptocoins-icons`.
The package is added in my project.json.

Now in one my html when I write - `<td><i class="cc BTC"></i>{{item.name}}</td>`

**`<i class="cc BTC">`** part should have displayed bitcoin icon there.

I know I am definitely missing something, but I don't know what. Please help

Comment: first you need to add the library on html in <script> tag then you have to include the library module in your main module

Comment: I tried angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.main', ['cryptocoins-icons']) - it gave error

Comment: you also need to include  css and js files of the cryptocoins-icons lib with <link> and <script> tags on your main html

Comment: got it right. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like my current solution but is working at least until I find something better.

After installing the dependency:

```
npm install cryptocurrency-icons
```

Then you can copy inside your assets folder:

```
cp node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/* src/assets/cryptoicons/
```

With this trick you can create an img like this:

```
<img src="/assets/cryptoicons/{{symbol}}.svg"/>
```

Where symbol is the crypto symbol (for example waves or xlm).

Not a very clean solution but... it works (ideally I would like to use the typical css icon-waves style).
Hope it helps!